# What would cause this button & text to not be inline?

Tags: html, css

Situation: 3 buttons in our application's header row. Formatted like:

```
<ul> class="menu dropdown clearfix">
    <li class="{buttonlabel}">
        <a href="#">
            <span> </span>
            <strong>{ButtonLabel}</strong>
        </a>
</li>
```

The `<span>` CSS has a background-image to display an icon (appx 20px square).

So, basically, you've got inline unordered list items that are the buttons. Each list item has a span (the icon) and a strong (the button label).

Now--2 computers/users. Same OS (Mac). Same browser (Chrome). Same website/URL. One user sees them as expected--which is, all of the list items are inline with each other, and then the content within the list items (the button and label) are also inline--button then label.

The other user sees the content within each list item as block (effectively). On the top line the icon is displayed. Then a break (not literal html break, just next line) and the button label is displayed below the icon. Their left margins line up.

I tried to reproduce on the 'working' list items by shrinking browser width to see if the buttons 'broke' to a smaller state at some point--they didn't.

The `<li>` display value is display: list item (width auto inherited). The `<a>` tag is display: block (width auto inherited). `<span>` is display:inline-block, with a coded width (24px) (not width auto or inherited width). The `<strong>` is also display: inline-block, width: auto (inherited).

What makes it worse is that the user seeing the wrong thing said it was normal Monday, wrong Tuesday.

Thoughts?

Comment: check the dev tools in each browser and see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Is `display: list-item` not the default vertically aligned items? Would that not need to be inline or inline-block too?

Comment: Marc B, of course I did that. I'm not actually able to reproduce the problem (the break in line) so dev tools don't really show me what's going on. Also, I am in Columbus, the user having issues is in Chicago. 
Chris--I would think so also, but that would/should be impacting the series of buttons, not the content inside the buttons (each of which have been explicitly declared as inline-block).
Also--just one more note--I didn't write the original code, I'm just supporting it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood slightly. Have you got the users to clear out their caches, etc. in case they have an old stylesheet cached or something? Don't know how agressive your caching is but this sort of problem (two users apparently lookign at the same thing but seeing something different) sounds like it could be something like that...

Comment: That is our next step right now--caching and possible different versions of Chrome...

Comment: If a new version of the stylesheet is available a good webserver should inform the client, that the old one is expired ... of course there is not garuntee that it will, and there is no garuntee that the client will bother listening, web development is a bit of a nightmare. I used to think that webdev oversimplifed the art of programming– but now I applaud web developpers for having the kahunas to put up with every web browser wanting to do things their own way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should load the backup on monday, and do a "diff" on tuesday to see what has changed, since it worked before, it is probably not the fault of the platform on which it was run, but rather that someone changed the code such that one browser is able to resolve it and another is not.  Human error is why version control was invented.

If that doesn't work, remember to validate your XHTML and CSS, to make sure an error syntax isn't the problem.  The purpose of these validators is to insure that if valid the code will display as expected, if it does not, it is the fault of the browser manufacturer, and should be reported as a bug.

http://validator.w3.org/

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I am positive that code validators on this CSS will puke horribly, I've done it before. I'll kick the other comment over to my developer coworker to see what he thinks! Thanks!

Comment: We use subversion btw, so yeah, version control is there. But this was literally two users, same OS, same browser, looking at same code base/URL at the same time with two different results.

Answer (score 0):

```
hai i think you initalize the class out of ul tag. so you put the class in inside ul tag.


<ul class="menu dropdown clearfix">
    <li class="{buttonlabel}">
        <a href="#">
            <span> </span>
            <strong>{ButtonLabel}</strong>
        </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So, first, I didn't create the code--I'm trying to debug it. {buttonlabel} and {ButtonLabel} are actually different. For example, one list item/button is "time" for the li and "My Time" for the actual button text.